# Uniform convergence of the power series except at the point 1.

Tags: complex-analysis

I couldn't solve the following problem from Lieb's Complex Analysis.
Let $a_k$ be a decreasing sequence of real numbers that converge to $0$ and suppose that the radius of convergence of the series $\Sigma_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kz^k$ is $1$. How can we show that for every $\delta>0$ the series converges uniformly on $\bar{\mathbb{D}}\setminus D_{\delta}(1)$.(which means 1 is the only point on $\partial D$ at which it could diverge)

The hint in the book is to estimate the sum $(1-z)\Sigma_{k=m}^{n}a_kz^k$.

I tried to do the following: We choose $\delta>0$.

Claim $1$:
 $(1-z)\Sigma_{k=m}^{n}a_kz^k$ is absolutely uniformly convergent on $M:=\{z ||z|<1 \textit{ and } |z-1|<\delta\}$ therefore there exists index $n_0$ such that for all $n>m>n_0$ and $z\in M$ $$|(1-z)\Sigma_{k=m}^{n}a_kz^k|<\delta$$.

I am not sure if I am on the right track, could someone give me a hint, or some neater proof?

Comment: Just a comment on why looking at $(1-z)\sum a_kz^k$ is reasonable: It is the same trick as in how you would compute $1+\ldots+z^n$. You have now coefficients in front of $z^k$, but it turns out harmless if they are decreasing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to expand

$$(1-z) \sum_{k=m}^n a_kz^k = \sum_{k=m}^n a_k z^k - \sum_{k=m}^n a_kz^{k+1} = a_mz^m + \sum_{k=m+1}^n (a_k - a_{k-1})z^k - a_nz^{n+1}$$

and use the monotonicity of $(a_k)$ to estimate

$$\left\lvert \sum_{k=m+1}^n (a_k - a_{k-1})z^k\right\rvert \leqslant \sum_{k=m+1}^n \lvert a_k - a_{k-1}\rvert \cdot \lvert z\rvert^k.$$

Comment: But what would this estimation give me?

Comment: Since $\lvert z\rvert \leqslant 1$, you can estimate the $\lvert z\rvert^k$ factors by $1$, leaving you with $\sum_{k=m+1}^n \lvert a_k - a_{k-1}\rvert$. Then use the monotonicity. What do you get?

Comment: I get $\Sigma_{k=m+1}^n|a_k-a_{k-1}|=a_m-a_n$. In general: $|(1-z)\Sigma_{k=m}^na_kz^k|\le|a_m|+|a_n|+a_m-a_n$ in the unitray disk. How do I proceed from here?

Comment: Now use that $(a_k)$ is a decreasing sequence of real numbers converging to $0$. Hence $a_k \geqslant 0$ for all $k$, and your upper bound simplifies to $2a_m$. Then divide: $$\left\lvert \sum_{k=m}^n a_k z^k\right\rvert \leqslant \frac{2a_m}{\lvert 1-z\rvert}.$$ Now use $\lvert 1-z\rvert \geqslant \delta$, and choose $m$ large enough.

Comment: If you choose $m$ large enough the bound goes to zero so $|\Sigma_{k=m}^{n}a_kz^k|=0$??

Comment: Not $= 0$ (unless $a_k = 0$ for all large enough $k$), but - with $\delta > 0$ fixed - for any given $\varepsilon > 0$, you can find an $M$ such that for all $M \leqslant m \leqslant n$ you have $$\left\lvert \sum_{k=m}^n a_k z^k\right\rvert < \varepsilon$$ for all $z \in \overline{\mathbb{D}}\setminus D_\delta(1)$. And that is the uniform convergence on $\overline{\mathbb{D}}\setminus D_\delta(1)$ you want to show.

Comment: Oh my goodness! I get it now! Thank you so much! This was extremely helpful! :)